# iPhone, iPad versions mixed in simulator

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I created a iPhone application first and converted it to iPad version to make it a universal build. Most of the time it works fine. But sometimes my iPhone version load as iPad and iPad version launches as iPhone. Kind of mixed up. What is the cause for this? Will this be an issue in actual devices once I submit that to the app store?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode you can select the active executable (use the drop-down in the upper-left corner).  I find that sometimes it switches on me, perhaps showing iPad and requiring me to set it back to the iPhone executable for example.  If this is your issue, there will not be any confusion when you're running it on an actual device.

If you are planning to submit an app to the app store, it's a very good idea (understatement) to test the app on real devices first!

Comment: Still this is reproducible in simulator and device :( This is not the issue.

Comment: Ok, then please give more specifics about what is happening.  For example, perhaps one or two design elements that are supposed to be appearing in the iPad are instead appearing on the iPhone and vice-versa?  There might be a logical reason for that.  Tell us more about what the exact symptoms are.